# Can a normal antivirus protect you from WannaCry or other ransomware?

Tags: windows, security, malware, anti-virus

My understanding is that the WannaCry ransomware spreads itself using two mechanisms:

- Opening an infected email attachment
- Exploiting a remote code execution vulnerability in *another* computer

Looking at the amount of damage it has done, I am wondering if using a decent, up-to-date antivirus is sufficient to protect me from such attacks.

I wuld also like to know what exactly can happen if the attacker uses a vulnerability that was undiscovered until the attack (in case of WannaCry a patch was published few weeks before the attack so the blame was, in part, put on users for not keeping their OS up-to-date).

Comment: The majority of security products on the market already block the original variation of WannaCry, the problem is, the author(s) of WannaCry have shown an active desire to continue to spread it.  `Microsoft Security Essentials` and `Windows Defender` both detect the original variation of WannaCry

Comment: @Ramhound so is it possible for an antivirus to not detect the variants? That is part of my question.

Comment: @SalmanA very possible. Either because it's not been updated, or because the variant is different enough that it doesn't match - the same way you get colds, because the rhinovirus mutates each time it spreads. Eventually you're body no longer knows it's the rhinovirus anymore and doesn't stop it.

Comment: I've added to my answer an answer about 0days. Hope that helps explain things for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159337/56967

Basically as long as you've applied the correct patches (MS17-010 -
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx) then you've already closed the exploit that it used to spread.

**Also having a good solid anti-malware solution will help, if it's got up to date definitions for this worm. However the worm can easily be changed which may leave you still open to attack.** - So yes, it *can* help, but it's not the be all and end all of solutions.

Finally, having up to date properly stored backups is the best defence.

As for what happens if an attacker uses a previously unknown attack - this is known as a Zero day (0day) - as in you find out only about the weakness by it's being exploited. What happens isn't something that can easily be answered - it can vary from the system has no defence against this type of attack at all to the fact the attack succeeds but in fact gives little to no help to the attacker.

This can vary due to many things such as security tools which maybe monitoring and 'notice' the attack, alerting someone, to A/V that uses heuristics to identify and stop viruses before they can proceed to trip wire systems which simply lock down a system the moment something happens which is unexpected.

Comment: Were antivirus able to detect this particular malware?

Comment: Do you mean prior to the attack? Some claim they did but I've seen nothing concrete. I think the fact it didn't spread the way some worms have spread rapidly shows a lot of systems were already immune to this attack, either because of the updates being applied, or due to other security in place.

Comment: *Were antivirus able to detect this particular malware?* - I read this statement incorrectly as "What AV able to detect this particular malware" due to the it being 7AM